# How to update this php code without having to reload the page?

Tags: php, reload

I dont know much about php. That said, is it possible to update the output of this statement without reloading the page?

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'];
```

Comment: What do you mean by reloading the page? Reloading in the browser? Or requesting the page from the server? If it's the first one (browser), you can use Ajax: perform a HTTP request to the server using Javascript and handle the result in the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called JavaScript and the answer is yes, you can. However, you cannot do it with PHP or any other server-side scripting. And why? Because it's executed on the server while you want to present it to the client. Unless you very explicitly tell the webbrowser to poll for new information (usually via JavaScript), it will not talk to the server again until the user either reloads or opens a new page.

Comment: How do i do that with javascript then?

Comment: That really depends on a large number of factors, including when you want it to reload and other things. The simplest version would be `<a onclick="document.body.innerHTML += document.cookie;">Get my cookie</a>`. I really suggest that you learn a programming language though.

Comment: <a onclick="document.body.innerHTML += document.cookie;">Get my cookie</a> has set me on the right direction! thanks Tom! I have been learning javascript, but i in way over my head with php.

Answer (score 0):

php is a server side script you could not instantly change the value of this variable

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'];
```

without reloading the page. it's possible with AJAX but that doesn't mean that it will be implemented on that same page your currently accessing.